# Combinatorics - letters forbidden sequence.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

I am trying to solve a question. I have 15 pens, where 5 are colored in Red, 5 in Green, and 5 in Blue. How many combinations can I order these pens so that there is no sequence of 5 pens with the same color? For instance, the combination RRRRG GGGBB BBRGB is okay because there is no sequence of pens where 5 colors are after each other. The combination RRRRR ... would need to be excluded because 5 red pens are in a row.

My initial strategy was to count the total number of combinations to build with these pens and then subtract the total number of combinations where at least 5 colors are in sequence.

The total number of combinations:

$$\frac{15!}{(5!*5!*5!)} = 756756$$

The issue I am having is how to create all the combinations where 5 colored pens are in order. I have tried to do something like this:

Group the sequence RRRRR into one symbol. Now, calculate every combination with this RRRRR symbol and the other symbols.

$$\frac{11!}{5!*5!}=2772$$

The problem here is that if I multiplied this with 3 to get the combinations from every color, there would be many duplicated combinations.

Any help on how I could solve this is much apprecited.

Comment: You're doing well.  Google "inclusion and exclusion".

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the answer! I think I was able to solve the question after reading about that principle!

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Answer (score 3):

You are very close to the correct solution. The  metod of choice for solving such problems is the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Applying it to the problem and taking into account the symmetry between the colors one obtains:
$$
\binom30\frac{15!}{5!5!5!}-\binom31\frac{11!}{5!5!1!}+\binom32\frac{7!}{5!1!1!}-\binom33\frac{3!}{1!1!1!}=748560.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a quick question if you have time to answer. How did you decide on all of your chooses, 3 choose 0, etc. When I calculate their respected values, I understand why I would have those values. But I do not understand the reasoning behind the specific chooses.

Comment: @robeng This is because of the symmetry beween the colors. The coefiicient $\binom nk$ just counts the number of ways to choose $k$ colors out of $n$ (in this case $k$ colors joined in a sequence of 5). Look also [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#A_special_case).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generating function approach. Words with no consecutive equal characters at all are called Smirnov words or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a ternary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{3z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since each letter may occur in runs with length $\leq 4$ we substitute
\begin{align*}
z\to z+z^2+z^3+z^4=\frac{z\left(1-z^4\right)}{1-z}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We substitute (2) in (1) and obtain the generating function $f(z)$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}=\left(1-\frac{3\,\frac{z\left(1-z^4\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^4\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
> \color{blue}{=\left(1-\frac{3}{1+\frac{1-z}{z\left(1-z^4\right)}}\right)^{-1}}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

The coefficient $[z^{15}]f(z)$ gives the number of all words of length $15$ built from the alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{R,G,B\}$ which do not contain characters with runs of length $5$. Since we are interested in the number of words which contain five $R$s, five $G$'s and five $B$'s we parametrize the function $f(z)$ and obtain from (3) with some help of Wolfram Alpha the number of valid words:

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[R^5G^5B^5z^{15}]f(z;R,G,B)}
> &=[R^5G^5B^5z^{15}]\left(1-\sum_{q\in\{R,G,B\}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-qz}{qz\left(1-(qz)^4\right)}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=748\,560}
> \end{align*}